# Hibernate getitem or getlist with 1 element which is better?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, repository

Lets assume we have one service class **CustomService** and it is calling repository class **CustomServiceRepository**. There are already implemented method for **getItemAList** which returns a list in both service and repository class.

Now i need to add getItemA methods (only 1 element of A not a list).

Which one is better or correct:
1-Just create method for it in service class and call the corresponding repository class method(**getItemA**)

2-Just create a List in service class with 1 element of A and call the already implemented method in repository and return a element list so do not touch the repository class?

Answer (score 0):

Regards,

Don't exist a correct method, exist methods.
One method is:

```
String HQL = "from CustomEntity where (Condition)";
Query query = EntityManager.createQuery(query);
query.setMaxResults(1);
```

This is similar to LIMIT in SQL, or you can use

```
EntityManager.find (Entity, Primary Key)
```

Depend of your application, about the call method, the recommended is create a method on Service layer and implements in DAO layer. Remmember, the Service layer is a layer of business rule, and DAO of transaction on DataBase.